# How to remove all pins Google Maps V3?

Tags: ajax, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently working on a code where we have a world map. On this map, the users position (you) is marked with a white marker. And there is so called "drivers" which drive around on our globe. The drivers position is taken from an API which my friend has written. But now to the problem, when our site here grabs values from all drivers which is shown on the API, it add their position. Then after 3000 ms, it grabs values again. Which means that drivers pins adds again, again and again, over each other. That due to my loop which grabs values from our API every 3000 ms. How could I use the code I got now, and make all drivers pins to be removed 100 ms before values are grabbed from my API?

Demo: http://profusum.se/bc/map/ (Notice that the pins are getting "greener") 
jsFiddle: http://goo.gl/8fQS1 (Shorted URL to "jsFiddle=zMYSw"

NOTICE
My jsFiddle may not work, if so, please comment and I will update this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing a reference to each "driver" in an array and then either call setMap(null) on each one at the start of your handleData() function, or modify your handleData() function to just update the position of each one.

Comment: Could be easy, if the drivers where static. But I will give it a go!

Comment: The drivers being dynamic shouldn't be a problem as long as you update your list after every update. I would start with calling setMap(null)  on each one first. That will remove the objects from the map. Then empty your array. Then, in your loop to add each driver to the map, add the driver to your list as well. Hope that helps! Let me know if you need it better explained and I'll write some pseudo code for you.

Comment: I'd appreciate if if you marked this as your answer if it helped; if it didn't, I'd be happy to help some more. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I'm working on it! Doesn't have my laptop ever since so. Hold on! :)

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to make sure you got it working. Thanks! :)